# How to use Turtle graphics to draw a series of parallel lines in python?

Tags: python, lines

How i can draw a series(ex:5) of parallel lines by turtle in python?

```
def parallel_lines(number):
    #Help me write the body of the function
    #number is the number of lines for drawing
```

Comment: What starting conditions? What direction? How long? How far apart? Have you even tried?

Comment: im really new at this, i want 5 lines to cover the whole screen vertically and equally distant apart being parallel. i know its probably a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
from turtle import *
#we make an object from class Turtle
alex=Turtle()
def parallel_lines(number):
    #number is number of lines
    with_s=alex.window_width()
    height_s=alex.window_height()
    alex.setheading(90)
    alex.pu()
    #for fill all screen and equall distance below line needed
    alex.setposition(with_s/-2,height_s/-2)
    for i in range(1,number+1):
        alex.pd()
        alex.fd(height_s)
        alex.pu()
        alex.setposition(with_s/-2+i*(with_s/(number-1)),height_s/-2)

parallel_lines(5)
```

`output` is 2 line in edge and 3 line in screen

Comment: thanks very much, but what's with the alex = turtle() part and how did you know to use the setheading(90) and alex.setposition(with_s/-2, height_s/-2) what is -2?

Comment: @ user2269635 i update answer.if you search turtle and documentation .it is very easy to find setposition(90)

Comment: @ user2269635 (with_s/-2, height_s/-2) by-2 is for move alex to left and Down of screen

Comment: how would one increase the size of each line? like making the width a little bigger?

Comment: @ user2269635 you can use alex.pensize(number)-alex.pencolor(red) or other

Comment: what's the pixel difference between the parallel lines?

Comment: Also with_s/-2, height_s/-2 could you explain this

Comment: @ user2269635 pixel difference between the parallel lines is depend on your turtle size screen. with_s/-2, height_s/-2(i explain in above comment)